# Condition to check project and execute the code in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We have terraform code base that is used for multiple projects in GCP (Project A, B, C, D), we want to exclude some firewall rule for a certain project lets say project B.

How can we create a condition so that a certain firewall rule is not created specially for project b, but is created for all others.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your TF code demonstration what you want to do and errors you get?

Comment: I still have to start to code, the scenario same repo will be used by 4 projects but there are couple of firewall rules that we need to exclude for a project.